# ROS Groovy Turtlebot Install from Debs Path error

Tags: ros, turtlebot, kobuki, groovy-turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I am following the instructions from here:
ros.org/wiki/turtlebot/Tutorials/groovy/Installation

Doing the debs installation to create my turtlebot computer.

I got all the way down to:

One last step if you have a kobuki base, you'll need to add kobuki's udev rules (you'll need your sudo password):

> . /opt/turtlebot/groovy/setup.bash
> rosrun kobuki_ftdi create_udev_rules

And encountered a small problem:

/opt/turtlebot/ does not exist.

Suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55105/ros-groovy-turtlebot-install-from-debs-path-error/) by [kpowell34567](https://answers.ros.org/users/4168/kpowell34567/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-02-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem. My directory is

. /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash rosrun kobuki_ftdi create_udev_rules

instead of

. /opt/turtlebot/groovy/setup.bash rosrun kobuki_ftdi create_udev_rules

---

Originally posted by [teichel1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4190/teichel1/) with karma: 51 on 2013-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2013-02-21**:
Yes, there was a typo on the tutorial that's been fixed since. Thanks.